# JMeter Issue- java.io.InvalidClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use JMeter [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) on a JMeter distributed environment. JMeter master was configured with the JMeter Maven plugin. I have added the required plugins on the pom.xml and JMeter slave nodes. I double-checked my plugin versions on both sides and can confirm those versions are similar.

JMeter master runs with below dependencies list

```
                   <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-autostop:0.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.9</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.6</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-csvars:0.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-functions:2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:1.4</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-perfmon:2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-prmctl:0.4</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-tst:2.5</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:3.2</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-dummy:0.4</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-graphs-basic:2.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-parallel:0.9</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set:0.6</artifact> 
                    </jmeterExtensions>
```

But I am observing the following on the execution logs. Appreciate someone can give some guidance over here. Btw I am using JMeter 5.3 version.

```
[INFO]  java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
[INFO]  java.io.InvalidClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4905624732580509862, local class serialVersionUID = -8557540133988335686
[INFO] Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
[INFO]  java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
[INFO]  java.io.InvalidClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4905624732580509862, local class serialVersionUID = -8557540133988335686
[INFO] [INFO ] 2021-08-04 10:51:49,112 DistributedRunner.println() - Remote engines have been started:[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), the [VariableThroughputTimer](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/tst/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/timers/VariableThroughputTimer.java) class is present in 2 libraries:

1. `kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.4.0`
2. `kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-tst:2.5`

and they seem to have different `serialVersionUID` field.

You need to either choose only one library, once you do and remove the extra .jars from [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) the issue should be resolved.

On the slave machines you can install/uninstall/upgrade the plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), it can also be used from the [command line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your answer, I will check on this approach.